# PHP url editing

Tags: php, html, api, int

Ok, so i am working on this and i ran into a problem. So i have the following problem...

The url is : http://api.(Sitehere).com/api.php?username=[USERNAME]&free

now this is nice and all but in PHP on the site i am working on i want to insert where it says "USERNAME" and want to change that to $name so when the API is accessed it will be accessed with $name instead of "USERNAME" in the brackets.

So this is what i came up with, I am not the best at this. I am just learning so please do forgive me!

```
@file_get_contents ("http://api.(SiteHere).com/api.php?username=[USERNAME]&free");
```

So i was thinking maybe urlencode? But it would have to change just whats in the brackets "USERNAME". And "&free" would still have to be a part of the url for it to function.

I can't change anything with the API as i do not own it. I am just allowed to use it.

I would be very thankful for any help! I am a new user to this site so please forgive me if i did anything wrong.

Comment: What leads to the URL ? A form ?

Comment: The url is simply an api. when the username is entered it will then spit out username info of the user. So when a button is click it will spit out user info on my webpage. It will not redirect or anything like that. So yes, A form i believe.

Comment: So the user enters its username and it will send him to : "http://api.(SiteHere).com/api.php?username=[USERNAME]&free" ?

Comment: No it will not, it will display information in a box. The user will never see the API link or any info about the API.

Comment: If your question is "How to change the url while having a variable" you can simply do as follow : `$url = "http://api.(SiteHere).com/api.php?username=".$name."&free";` If you need info about how to use the api you'll have to be more precise.

Comment: sorry, did you mean like it? `$url = 'http://api.(SiteHere).com/api.php?username=[USERNAME]&free';
$parse_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parse_url['query'], $param);
echo $param['username'];` output: [USERNAME].

Answer (score 0):

```
$url_template = "http://api.(SiteHere).com/api.php?username=%s&free";
$url = sprintf($url_template, urlencode($username));
@file_get_contents ($url);
```